# Simplify $ABC+A'BC+AB'C+A'B'C'$ to logic gates

Tags: boolean-algebra

I've simplified $ABC+A'BC+AB'C+A'B'C'$ to $BC+AC+A'B'C'$. However, I want to go further to logic gates for which ICs are readily available. I would like to use at most three such ICs.

Comment: ICs? Circuit? You should clarify what you mean. Also, it may be that you've already simplified it as far as it'll go, but there'll be no way for us to say one way or the other, unless you include your work so far.

Comment: Now check the question. I added details.

Comment: I suggest you take this question to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic gates commonly implemented in TTL/CMOS ICs are two-input OR, AND and XOR, their negations and NOT. I will interpret "IC" in the question as one of these logic gates, so we are looking to use at most three logic gates to represent the given expression. Let's simplify it on paper first:
$$ABC+A'BC+AB'C+A'B'C'$$
$$=(AB+A'B+AB')C+(A+B)'C'$$
$$=(A+B)C+(A+B)'C'$$
$$=(A+B)\odot C$$
where $\odot$ is the XNOR gate, returning 1 iff both inputs are equal.

Immediately we have the admissible representations `(A OR B) XNOR C` and (if XNOR is not available as a single chip) `NOT((A OR B) XOR C)`.

Comment: Thanks. You really helped me great.

Comment: @umairmughal Now, please accept my answer. You are new, so I'll tell you: click the check mark next to me answer. Details are in the help.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this won't be strictly a math answer, but since you asked for IC circuits, then I would suggest you use **Logic Friday**, enter an expression, select the gates you want and it draws the minimal circuit.

For instance here with standard gates (thus excluding XNOR) you'll use $2$ of them :

```
(A nor B) xor C
```

If you want only NAND and OR gates then you'll use $4$ of them :

```
((A or B) or C) nand ((A or B) nand C)
```

Note also that since XNOR is the mathematical equivalent of "$?\atop\iff$"

we can also use a $3$-input MUX gate which select the ouput according to its third entry:

MUX(u,v,s) = if (s=0) then u else v

```
(A or B) xnor C   is equivalent to   MUX( not(A or B), (A or B), C )
```